# How do I resolve 'GraphKeys' Attribute Error while importing Tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow, python-import, tensorlayer

I am trying to run the following codes:

```
import os
import pprint
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
import tensorlayer as tl
from tensorlayer.layers import *
from tensorlayer.prepro import *
from random import shuffle
```

However, I am getting this error:

```
~\Documents\Jupyter Notebooks far Run\cGAN at Lockdown\Re-implement CycleGAN in 
Tensorlayer=GD\CycleGAN_Tensorlayer-master\tensorlayer\layers.py in <module>
 31     TF_GRAPHKEYS_VARIABLES = tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES
 32 except:  # For TF11 and before
---> 33     TF_GRAPHKEYS_VARIABLES = tf.GraphKeys.VARIABLES
 34 
 35 ## Variable Operation

AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'GraphKeys'
```

The version of my tf is 2.0.0-beta1 while I have installed TensorLayer 2.2.1

Kindly let me know where I am getting it wrong.

Comment: What version of TensorFlow do you have? Is it supported by the version of TensorLayer that you use?

Comment: @MatiasValdenegro, the version of my tf is 2.0.0-beta1 while I have installed TensorLayer 2.2.1